# ASP.NET Reverse Loop

Tags: asp.net, loops, reverse

I have some code and I'm trying to do my `For` loop in reverse and it doesn't seem to work

```
Session("mysession") = "1234-5678-"

Dim delimiters As Char() = New Char() {"-"C}

Dim mystring As String() = Trim(Session("mysession")).Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

For x = 0 to mystring.Length - 1 

    'Do Something

Next
```

That works but shows it in the wrong order I'm trying to reverse it by simply doing this

```
For mystring.Length - 1 to x = 0
```

But I'm getting an error

```
Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of your reversed loop is incorrect. It should be:

```
For x = mystring.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
```

Comment: Or [`Array.Reverse(mystring)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx) if you're mentally lazy/before coffee sets in.